# Flexbox layout with on column fluid and the other fixed width

Tags: html, css, flexbox, multiple-columns, vertical-alignment

On **[THIS](http://develop.rol.ro/companie/english-valori-in-care-credem/)** page I have a layout with rows of *text-photo pairs*. I need the photo to have a fixed width and the text to have fluid width. The text has to be *vertically centered*. I have used flexbox to achieve these goals.

As can be seen below, in the list item with the *id of **box2***, in order to place the photo to the left, I had to insert it **before** the text block in the DOM.

The problem: on small, mobile resolutions, when the display goes to block instead of flex, *the photos* of the first and second row *are one after the other*, when instead, there should be a block of text between them.

How can I fix that?

```css
h3 {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 65px 0;
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}
ul.boxes {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
ul.boxes li {
  color: #3e3e3e;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}
ul.boxes #box1 {
  background: #dcdcdc;
}
ul.boxes #box3 {
  background: #6b6b6b;
  color: #fff;
}
ul.boxes li .photo {
  width: 402px;
  max-width: 100%;
}
ul.boxes li .content {
  padding: 0 65px;
  width: 100%;
}
ul.boxes li h4 {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-top: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
ul.boxes li .content ul {
  padding: 0;
}
ul.boxes li .content ul li {
  padding-left: 20px;
  background: transparent url('img/redbullet.png') no-repeat 5px 8px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  ul.boxes,
  ul.boxes li {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<h3 class="text-center thin">Obiectivul nostru este să fim în fiecare zi mai buni, iar munca noastră se bazează pe 3 piloni principali:
 Calitate, Creativitate, Rezultate.</h3>
<ul class="boxes">
  <li id="box1">
    <div class="content">
      <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta, reiciendis molestias inventore blanditiis ratione amet, dolore id doloribus minus iure esse, accusantium qui ex, nesciunt? Officiis, animi saepe libero quae!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="photo flex-left">
      <div class="photo flex-right">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/402x335">
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li id="box2">
    <div class="photo flex-right">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/402x335">
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor</h4>
      Descoperim continuu soluții noi pentru a ne îndeplini sarcinile și pentru a trece peste provocările zilnice, ca să fim în fiecare zi mai buni.
    </div>
  </li>
  <li id="box3">
    <div class="content">
      <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta, reiciendis molestias inventore blanditiis ratione amet, dolore id doloribus minus iure esse, accusantium qui ex, nesciunt? Officiis, animi saepe libero quae!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="photo flex-left">
      <div class="photo flex-right">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/402x335">
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `display: block` below (and including) 480px, you can *wrap* your `flexbox` and set order for the flex children like this:

```
  ul.boxes,
  ul.boxes li {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  ul.boxes li .photo {
    order: 2;
  }
  ul.boxes li .content {
    order: 1;
  }
```

I guess now you can take it forward from here - see demo below:

```css
h3 {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 65px 0;
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}
ul.boxes {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
ul.boxes li {
  color: #3e3e3e;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}
ul.boxes #box1 {
  background: #dcdcdc;
}
ul.boxes #box3 {
  background: #6b6b6b;
  color: #fff;
}
ul.boxes li .photo {
  width: 402px;
  max-width: 100%;
}
ul.boxes li .content {
  padding: 0 65px;
  width: 100%;
}
ul.boxes li h4 {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-top: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
ul.boxes li .content ul {
  padding: 0;
}
ul.boxes li .content ul li {
  padding-left: 20px;
  background: transparent url('img/redbullet.png') no-repeat 5px 8px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  ul.boxes,
  ul.boxes li {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  ul.boxes li .photo {
    order: 2;
  }
  ul.boxes li .content {
    order: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<h3 class="text-center thin">Obiectivul nostru este să fim în fiecare zi mai buni, iar munca noastră se bazează pe 3 piloni principali:
 Calitate, Creativitate, Rezultate.</h3>
<ul class="boxes">
  <li id="box1">
    <div class="content">
      <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta, reiciendis molestias inventore blanditiis ratione amet, dolore id doloribus minus iure esse, accusantium qui ex, nesciunt? Officiis, animi saepe libero quae!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="photo flex-left">
      <div class="photo flex-right">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/402x335">
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li id="box2">
    <div class="photo flex-right">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/402x335">
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor</h4>
      Descoperim continuu soluții noi pentru a ne îndeplini sarcinile și pentru a trece peste provocările zilnice, ca să fim în fiecare zi mai buni.
    </div>
  </li>
  <li id="box3">
    <div class="content">
      <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta, reiciendis molestias inventore blanditiis ratione amet, dolore id doloribus minus iure esse, accusantium qui ex, nesciunt? Officiis, animi saepe libero quae!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="photo flex-left">
      <div class="photo flex-right">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/402x335">
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```